# Problemas con Matplotlib.dates

Tags: python

Hola estimados amigos de Stack Over FLow,estoy tratando de correr matplotlib.dates por medio del siguiente código:

```
from matplotlib.dates import num2date, date2num, hours
```

Pero lamentablemente me sale este error:

```
from matplotlib.dates import num2date, date2num, hours
ImportError: cannot import name 'hours' from 'matplotlib.dates'
```

¿Que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias

Comment: estas en windows o linux?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es mas probable que sea por la version de matplotlib que usas, asi que te recomiendo usar una version en la que estes seguro de que exista esa funcion.

`pip install matplotlib==3.2.2`

En Google Colab, usan esa version de matplotlib y el import no da error.

[image: text]

Comment: No se por qué alguien te votaría negativo en lugar de agregar un comentario que aporte a la respuesta que de por sí no es incorrecta. La función `hours` [fue deprecada](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.hours) en la versión `3.1` y se removió en la versión `3.3`, por lo que, como bien dices, moviéndote a una versión más antigua funcionará, aunque no es lo recomendado. Justo si ejecutas `hours` en `Google Colab` con la versión `3.2.2` obtendrás un error: _"The hours function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3."_.